# How to optimize thread safe queue in Go?

Tags: go, concurrency, queue, thread-safety

I have the following request queue:

```
type RequestQueue struct {
    Requests []*http.Request
    Mutex *sync.Mutex
}

func (rq *RequestQueue) Enqueue(req *http.Request) {
    rq.Mutex.Lock()
    defer rq.Mutex.Unlock()
    rq.Requests = append(rq.Requests, req)
}

func (rq *queue) Dequeue() (*http.Request, error) {
    rq.Mutex.Lock()
    defer rq.Mutex.Unlock()
    if len(rq.Requests) == 0 {
        return nil, errors.New("dequeue: queue is empty")
    }
    req := rq.Requests[0]
    rq.Requests = rq.Requests[1:]
    return req, nil
}
```

Is it possible to do this with just the atomic package, without Mutex, type being simply `type AtomicRequestQueue []*http.Request`, and will that bring any performance benefit?

Comment: No, you need synchronization here which the mutex provides. Why not use a simple buffered channel, which is already highly optimized in the runtime?

Comment: @JimB Because afaik tt can't be dynamically resized.

Comment: That is rarely a real concern, since the max size should be bounded in some way anyway, and a channel has the benefit of being able to automatically block once the buffer is full.

Comment: It can be dynamically sized...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a channel, like `chan *http.Request`. A channel **is literally** a FIFO queue.

What you call `Enqueue` will just be a send operation `c <- req`, and what you call `Dequeue` will just be a receive operation `req := <-c`.

> Is it possible to do this with just the atomic package

You didn't state what is the real purpose of this thread-safe queue, however the use case you presented above seems to need synchronization, i.e. **mut**ual **ex**clusive access to the shared resource. The types in the `atomic` package only guarantee that the result of the operation will be observed by other threads in a consistent fashion. There's no mutual exclusiveness involved.

If your queue needs more business logic than you are actually showing, a channel might be too primitive; in that case mutex locking might be your best bet. You may use [`sync.RWMutex`](https://pkg.go.dev/sync#RWMutex) to reduce lock contention if you expect to have a lot of reads.